# MVC 3 - Simplifying routing: How do I? multiple URL matches in a single MapRoute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In my Global.asax.cs routing I have a bunch of routing entries like this:

```
      routes.MapRoute(
           name: "About",
           url: "about",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About" }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Buy",
           url: "buy",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Buy"}
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Blog",
           url: "blog",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Blog"}
       );
```

And so on - I could have facebook, twitter and so on, so that when people access
http://www.mywebsite.com/blog or /twitter or /facebook etc. I redirect them to the actual links.

Am I missing something obvious or is there a simpler way to combine all these in a single entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what route parameters are for:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{action}", new { controller = "home" });
```

Of course, this will catch any single word URL and then complain if that action doesn't exist in the home controller. You can map other routes before this one and they will take precedence.